# Snow line in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, line, modis

I am new in Google Earth Engine and need help to make the snow line on a merged product of MODIS for aqua and terra. So far, I made the function, union, threshold for NDSI to be greater than 0.4 and a mask, but I need to define the snow line and I don't know how to.

I enclose my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fca033adb8e5f3e39e067d1c14d62c69